# Why does IBM's Intrusion Detection System Show Local IPs instead of Public IPs for the Source of an Attack?

Tags: ids

Security Intern here given the assignment to find the IP address of an attacker using IBM's IDS.

The event or attack in question is entitled `X509_Weak_Signature_Algorithm`, and from what I understand, this attack involves exploiting *MD5* to generate rogue certificates to compromise our servers.

When I go to review an individual event log, I noticed that the attacker's IP address is a Class A local IP.

**Shouldn't this be a public IP address because we are being attacked by an external host?**

Comment: Depends on your architecture? We'll need more info to work on. Where is your IDS situated in relation to the Internet?

Comment: It really depends on the environment setup. In your case I guess the "attacker" is inside your network.

Comment: this really isn't an answer

Comment: @schroeder From what I understand, our IDS's are internal and do not sit on the perimeter of our network

Comment: And you are certain that the attack originated from an external source? Is the reported IP in your org's normal IP range? Do you use a proxy?

Comment: @cryc0s I appreciate the answer, but my coworker confirmed that this is not the case. He told me that the attacker's IP is from a foreign country.

Comment: Yes to all of your questions.

Comment: @user57339 I thot you said it was a private IP range?

Comment: There are a lot of reasons this could happen. Are you able to identify anything at all about the IP it was sourced from? It could be a load balancer pool or something similar, which would mean you'd have to look at the logs from that device (if they exist) to figure out more details. Unless there is a bug of some kind, the IDS can only report the IP it sees the attack from. NAT, Load Balancing, and other network tools may change the source IP while performing their functions.

Answer (score 2):

This is **not an attack**

The IDS is merely telling you that you have an SSL certificate with a weak algorithm. [more info](http://www.iss.net/security_center/reference/vuln/X509_Weak_Signature_Algorithm.htm)

The IP address is the address of your own internal server, that has the weak certificate.

Comment: I'd assume this too, but we're not getting enough detail and and the details we do get conflict.

Comment: [link](https://exchange.xforce.ibmcloud.com/signature/X509_Weak_Signature_Algorithm)  This is an audit, not an attack.  To remedy it you should contact the owner of the server and get them to regenerate the certificate using SHA-256 or better. Users to the site are likely getting certificate warnings about the weak algorithm.  You would get the same event if a malicious host was masquerading as the legitimate server (which means you don't know if this server is legitimate without additional information).